modemmanager stuck at registration
I have a dual SIM IOT device which was running modem-manager 1.10 on Ubuntu 16.04. Recently upgraded to modem-manager 1.20.0 on Ubuntu 22.04.
When switching from the first slot to the second slot, modem-manager is stuck with 3GPP status "registered" with the warning messages
[modem0/bearer1] connection attempt #3 failed: Couldn't find associated QMI port for 'net/wwp0s29u1u1i10'

I don't think it is a slot/SIM/APN issue because it gets data connection if the device is rebooted with the 2nd slot active.
SIM switch from 2nd slot to 1st slot works fine so can not be any issue with sim switch logic.
Any suggestion?
